# What are the steps involved in writing a Perl Code Generator in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, code-generation

Given that Perl 5 does not conform to BNF, I'm at a loss as to how to think about this problem. Could someone offer some advice to set me off in the right way thinking about this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you want to generate.

If the Perl code you wish to generate *does* conform to a BNF, then you clearly think (rightly) that there's a solution: build a tree corresponding to Perl fragment, and then prettyprint the tree.   This will only be an issue if you insist on generating the same syntax, which can be ambiguously interpreted by Perl.

You can also simply use text templates for the Perl code and fill in the slots.  If you code generator doesn't have to compose the pieces in complicated ways, this will work fine, too.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as right, even though I don't yet know that the perl code I need to generate will conform to a BNF. This bears further examination.